# Why is the speed of light limited to (only) 299.792.458 m/s?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, physical-constants

The speed of light (in a vacuum) is limited to 299.792.458 m/s. This sounds very fast, and it is on a global scale. But if you look at the Universe on a larger scale than it sounds quite slow, For instance it takes light from one and of the Milky way 100.000 years to get to the other end. So something is causing the light to travel at a speed of no more than this 299.792.458 m/s.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the speed of light limited to (only) 299.792.458 m/s?

Because space is the way it is. The speed of light is related to the [permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity) and [permeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permeability) of space via the expression: $$c_0={1\over\sqrt{\mu_0\varepsilon_0}}$$ See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permeability#Significance_in_electromagnetism). There's a somewhat similar expression for shear wave velocity in mechanics:  $$v_s = \sqrt{\frac {G} {\rho} }$$ Again see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_modulus#Waves). G is the shear modulus of rigidity and ρ is the density. Perhaps surprisingly, there's shear-stress term in the [stress-energy-momentum tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor).

> The speed of light (in a vacuüm) is limited to 299.792.458 m/s. This sounds very fast, and it is on a global scale. But if you look at the Universe on a larger scale than it sounds quite slow, For instance it takes light from one and of the Milky way 100,000 years to get to the other end. So something is causing the light to travel at a speed of no more than this 299,792,458 m/s.

Like I said, it's because space is the way it is. The speed of light is very fast. But the Milky Way is very *very* big. And the universe is even bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Scale is not symmetrical in physics.

Say, if you zoom in stuffs, you will eventually see atoms, which is totally different to the "continuous" things you see in your scale everyday.

Therefore, there is nothing special to find light move "not impressively" in a cosmic scale. Not to mention that being "fast" or "slow" is a matter of comparison.

Besides, while light indeed moves 299.792.458 m per second - usually considered true in all inertial frames, as we have done countless experiments on it.$^{[1]}$ - However, "does light move at the same rate **per year**?" is a question that I do not know, Which I believe is a question in the realm of general relativity, that I do not know. And I don't think it an easy question to answer, especially the universe is expanding.

What is that "thing" keeping the speed of light invariant in all inertial frames? We do not know (Maybe there is no such thing at all! Maybe it is just the way it is.). We simply assume "light invariant in all inertial frames.". and found out that the theory works so very well. The theory of special relativity even had predicted particles' existence that we had never ever dare to imagine, and physicists **did** find them empirically.

We have done experiments in which we have kept inputting energy to some particles, then we observed that they never get faster than the speed of light. You may question why, but we do not know$^{[2]}$.

In that sense, if you still insist to know further why, I am afraid that it is a question not in the realm of physics. (especially you can ask further why why .... why$^n$ that "thing" keeping things from faster than light.)

---

[1]: Now, we define distance in a way that it is always true.

[2]: One guess is that: All is the consequence of "symmetry of uniform velocity in a straight line". "symmetry of uniform velocity in a straight line" means a fact (you either accept it or give me a real counter example) that as long as you move in a straight line with uniform velocity, everything you see is the same, it is impossible for you to tell how fast you move (without looking out the window). it is kind of tautological, but symmetry is a better starting point  usually, and you need a starting point for physics anyway.

Comment: Perhaps there is a mechanism that keeps emanating energy after that barrier is crossed in the current universal context? Meaning, if the circumstances change, the barrier may change as well? Given the macroscopic time frames in play and the little period we performed experiments so far, a million years from now, a different context could be in play?